# How to access selectionStart/End from label in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this method in my angular Directive called on a label element:

```
@HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log("onMouseUp called");
    var el : HTMLInputElement  = event.target as HTMLInputElement ;
    console.log("S:" + el.selectionStart
      + " E:" + el.selectionEnd
    );
  }
```

When I print the value of `el.selectionStart` or `el.selectionEnd` it is always `undefined`.
What do I need to cast `event.target` to,  to have access to above properties.